# VNC feed from a remote server

Tags: jmeter, vnc

I want to measure the performance of the VNC feed from a remote server. The use case is, there will be a  user login to the remote server and doing some operations. There will be many other users viewing these operations through the VNC viewer (ssh connection). Based on the different network speed I want to measure the performance of the VNC feeds of the users who are viewing. How to achieve this through JMeter?
Note that the users who are viewing are not doing any operations on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

VNC and SSH are different beasts so your `VNC viewer (ssh connection)` stanza doesn't make a lot of sense, VNC is a separate protocol and JMeter doesn't support it either via its [samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or via [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

If you still want to use JMeter for load testing your VNC server you will need to implement the client login and getting initial image using some form of VNC Java client library like [Vernacular VNC](https://github.com/shinyhut/vernacular-vnc) from [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [come up with your own JMeter plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices/)